# Two qualify clause in same statement in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a requirement where in think i need two qualify clause in same statement.

I need two column one with correct iD's (duplicate_cnt=1) and other column with all other ids( dup_cnt>1).
Based on these values i have to update another table. Is this possible in teradata?

This is my table:

```
Name    Description  Code   Data_Source
A   XX  101 SCRM
A   XX  102 SCRM
A   XX  103 SCRM
A   XX  104 SCRM
A   XX  105 SCRM
A   XX  110 BSCRM
```

This is what i want:

```
Name    Description Correct_code    Incorrect code  Data_Source
A   XX  101 102 SCRM
A   XX  101 103 SCRM
A   XX  101 104 SCRM
A   XX  101 105 SCRM
```

Thanks,
AB

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define the "correct" code, the lowest value?

Use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the lowest value and a Cumulative Count to find the additional codes:

```
SELECT 
   Name
   ,Description
   ,First_Value(Code) -- lowest code
    Over (PARTITION BY Data_Source --, Name, Description?
          ORDER BY code) AS Correct_code
   ,code AS Incorrect_code
   ,Data_Source
FROM dropme
QUALIFY
   Count(*) -- only return rows with additional codes
   Over (PARTITION BY Data_Source --, Name, Description?
         ORDER BY code
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) > 1
```

Edit:

As long as the order & the data column are the same you can also use a simple

```
   ,MIN(Code) -- lowest code
    Over (PARTITION BY Data_Source --, Name, Description?
         ) AS Correct_code
```

Comment: Yes, Dnoeth the lowest value is the correct code. This one worked like a charm.
Thanks a ton!!

Comment: How do we pick the highest value here? LAST_VALUE??

Comment: `LAST_VALUE()  OVER (PARTITION BY Data_Source ORDER BY code ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)`, but as long as you look for the lowest/highest code you can simply use `MAX(code) OVER (PARTITION BY Data_Source)` instead. Only if the order column is different from the data column you need `FIRST/LAST_VALUE`.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot Dnoeth :)